# "На правой стороне устройства" или "с правой стороны устройства"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, при описании устройства какой вариант правильный?

> 1. Кнопки расположены на правой стороне устройства.
> 2. Кнопки расположены с правой стороны устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что более подходящим является вариант 2: "Кнопки расположены с правой стороны устройства".

Если использовать предлог НА, то лучше сказать, что кнопки расположены **на панели** с правой стороны (то есть **на какой-то  плоскости**). Именно в таких случаях обычно используется предлог НА.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант (Кнопки расположены на правой стороне устройства) грамматически верен, но стилистически неудачен, может быть оправдан только, если правая сторона представляет собой некую панель, на которой расположены кнопки.

Второй вариант (Кнопки расположены с правой стороны устройства) не верен грамматически, по-моему. "Расположен с правой стороны", подобно "расположен справa ", не сочетается с родительным падежом. Это подтвержадает и поиск в Нацкорпусе, который  дает несколько примеров типа "расположен/а/о/ы с правой/левой стороны", но там нет "расположен/а/о/ы с правой/левой стороны **чего-то**". Если нельзя сказать просто "Кнопки расположены с правой стороны", то могу предложить такой вариант:

**Кнопки расположены на устройстве с правой стороны.**